# Using iPhone SDK, be alerted of new SMS

Tags: iphone, sms

Is it possible to be notified programmatically (i'm not sure what sort of notification i require) of a user receiving an SMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK no, it's impossible.

Documentation quote - In iOS 4.0 and later, you can send text messages from within your application. This feature is strictly for sending messages. Incoming SMS messages go to the built-in Messages app.

Comment: ah interesting. Thats screws my app idea!

Comment: I forgot one think - it's possible, but not for applications for AppStore. Only for jailbroken devices.